# Switch XIB to View Controller from variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frameworks, uiviewcontroller

Im making a framework and I want to go back to a view controller that the publisher sets. Im using this code:

```
BV_APIViewControllerler *newView = [[BV_APIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
newView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentModalViewController:newView animated:YES];
[newView release];
```

But I want to switch to a view controller they save to NSUserDefaults

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the problem ? Juste read the name of the nib name stored in the defaults, and use it. The XIB file must reference BV_APIViewController as file's owner.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but Ok

Comment: @Sam Baumgarten : What did you look for precisely ?

Comment: nvm my mistake I miss understood your answer.  Its exactly what I was looking for